# How would you implement a limited time featured node?

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

I am using Drupal 6.

I would like to create for a limited time (start date, end date) another version of a node that would share almost all its properties. This featured version is in fact a recipe sponsored by a company, so we have to put the company logo, etc.

About the only thing that would change is a couple of line of data, another category (keeping the other ones) and the main image.

An exemple of the node I want to create a featured version is here :
http://www.moietcie.ca/cuisine/recettes/entrees-et-amuse-gueules/acras-de-morue

The big difficulty is to have the possibility to create a *temporary* version. After the date is passed, it must return to normal. Hence, I must keep all the data of the normal version.

I first thought of hijacking the translation system since we don’t use translations and force a fake language: French — Featured. Content without this translation would fallback to French (the normal version).

I did some quick tests, and beside the fact that my admin menu is now in English, it works but I hate my idea. I have to modify core modules of Drupal and I know this is bound to fail at some point.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Use [Scheduler module](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler) not Panels for it.

Comment: With [Scheduler](https://drupal.org/project/scheduler), you can set the date a node becomes published and/or unpublished automatically. In your described case, you would create several nodes: one for each variation of the text, then set all their publish/unpublish dates so that they change. Downsides: the different nodes will have different urls; bookmarks and permalinks will provide a "challenge" :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following, but it assume that you use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

1. Create a panel page.
2. Add your first node as Content.  Add a Visibility rule, choose PHP, and add in code that checks your date range based on the current time.
3. Add your second node as Content.  Add a Visibility rule, choose PHP, and add in inverse of the code above.

I wouldn't be surprised if you can also accomplish this with the [Scheduler](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler) module, but I am not sure how the URL would be handled in this scenario.